# How does jQuery use namespace to avoid conflict with other 3rd JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gone through the jQuery Source Code, but I cannot find how jQuery implement the namespace functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are handled in JavaScript by using function scope and objects.

jQuery exposes two global variables by default: `jQuery` and `$`.

You can do similar...

```
(function(global) { 
    global.someGlobalIdentifier = {
        // Whatever you want...
    };
})(this);
```